# How do I create new cells with FPDF using PHP if the number of name attributes in the DOM is unknown?

Tags: php, fpdf

I'm developing an invoice that can generate new input fields when user click on the ADD button to generate a new field. Then at the end of the document I made a "GET PDF" button that allows you to get a PDF copy of the invoice once is ready. In order to accomplish this I've been using the FPDF library and so far the application is working very well, except for one thing. The PDF document has to be basically built separately and I can't find a good way to make PHP look in to the file where I'm building the app and retrieve the name attributes with all values in order to inject them in the FPDF template I made in a different file. I'm new in PHP and I don't know how to go about this. The file that contains the Invoice App is called index.php and the file that contains the PDF template is in pdf.php

```
in index.php:
<form action="pdf.php" method="post">
 <div class="inputForms">
  <div id="input_fields" class="input_fields_wrap">
    <div class="new"><input  name="description" class="description"       type="text" maxlength="255" placeholder="Enter Description" value=""/>
                    <input  name="r" class="rate qty" type="text"  maxlength="255" placeholder="0" size="5" value=""/>
                    <input  name="p" class="pack price" type="text" maxlength="255" placeholder="$ 0.00" size="5" value=""/>
                    <input id="amount" class="amount" name="amount"   type="text"></div>
</div>
 </div>
</form>

in pdf.php:

<?php

$invoiceNumber = $_POST['InvoiceNumber'];
$clientName = $_POST['clientName'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$insurance_name = $_POST['insurance_name'];
$claim = $_POST['claim'];
$description = $_POST['description'];
$r = $_POST['r'];
$p = $_POST['p'];
$amount = $_POST['amount'];
$totalAmount = $_POST['total_amount'];
$afterTax = $_POST['after_tax'];
$notes = $_POST['notes'];
require("fpdf/fpdf.php");

$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont("Arial","",12);

$pdf->Cell(52);
$pdf->Cell(50,10,"The Company Name",1,0,"R");
$pdf->Cell(0,10,"INVOICE",1,1,"C");
$pdf->Cell(52);
$pdf->Cell(50,10,"City, State, Zip",1,0,"R");
$pdf->Cell(30,10,"Date:",1,0,"R");
$pdf->Cell(0,10,"04-15-2016",1,1,"L");
$pdf->Cell(52);
$pdf->Cell(50,10,"Phone: (555)777-7777",1,0,"R");
$pdf->Cell(30,10,"Time:",1,0,"R");
$pdf->Cell(0,10,"15 : 21 PM",1,1,"L");
$pdf->Cell(52);
$pdf->Cell(50,10,"Fax: (555)777-7777",1,0,"R");
$pdf->Cell(30,10,"#",1,0,"R");
$pdf->Cell(0,10,"{$invoiceNumber}",1,1,"L");
$pdf->Cell(52);
$pdf->Cell(0,10,"E-mail: something@example.com",1,1,"L");
$pdf->Image('images/hlogo.jpg',10,6,50);
$pdf->Cell(0,10,"",1,1,"C");
$pdf->Cell(90,10,"Bill To",1,0,"L");
$pdf->Cell(0,10,"Insurance Information",1,1,"L");
$pdf->Cell(90,10,"{$clientName}",1,0,"L");
$pdf->Cell(0,10,"{$insurance_name}",1,1,"L");
$pdf->Cell(90,10,"{$address}",1,0,"L");
$pdf->Cell(0,10,"{$claim}",1,1,"L");
$pdf->Cell(90,10,"{$phone}",1,0,"L");
$pdf->Cell(0,10,"",1,1,"C");
$pdf->Cell(0,10,"",1,1,"C");
$pdf->Cell(100,10,"item",1,0,"L");
$pdf->Cell(25,10,"Quantity",1,0,"C");
$pdf->Cell(25,10,"Rate",1,0,"C");
$pdf->Cell(0,10,"Amount",1,1,"C");

$pdf->Cell(100,10,"{$description}",1,0,"L");
$pdf->Cell(25,10,"{$r}",1,0,"C");
$pdf->Cell(25,10,"$ {$p}",1,0,"L");
$pdf->Cell(0,10,"$ {$amount}",1,1,"L");

$pdf->Cell(0,10,"",1,1,"C");
$pdf->Cell(150,10,"SubTotal",1,0,"R");
$pdf->Cell(0,10,"$ {$totalAmount}",1,1,"L");
$pdf->Cell(150,10,"Tax",1,0,"R");
$pdf->Cell(0,10,"% 6",1,1,"L");
$pdf->Cell(150,10,"Total",1,0,"R");
$pdf->Cell(0,10,"$ {$afterTax}",1,1,"L");
$pdf->Cell(0,10,"",1,1,"C");
$pdf->Cell(0,10,"Notes",1,1,"L");
$pdf->Cell(140,10,"{$notes}",1,1,"L");
$pdf->output();

?>
```

Comment: What do you mean if the number of name attributes of what is exactly unknown??

Comment: I should say in put fields because they have names with values like so name='something'. Then I take that name and insert it in $a = $_POST['something']. since I don't know how many input fields the user will need the PDF needs to generate the same amount of cells as the invoice file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would name the new fields with a pattern like "field_01", "field_02", etc. Then, you could loop through the created POST fields like so:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key=>$value){
if (substr($key,0,6) === "field_"){
        $pdf->Cell(140,10,"$value",1,1,"L");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy way to do this :

## By USING LOOP :

**Note :** You can always loop for things to do that more than a few times and yet you can make it dynamic like this way :

```
<?php
//Assuming that $data holds all the elements of your specific name attribute
$data = $_POST; 
for ($i=0;$i <= count($data);$i++) {
$pdf->Cell($i); //Here you can do whatever you want with your cell
}
?>
```

**Note :** As `$_POST` contains all your input field values if you are using POST Method in your form so it will count all those input fields and then it will create cells according to the number of fields..!

Comment: If I do this in my pdf.php file, is the file still going to know where the name attribute is coming from ? e.g $data = $_POST['somename'];

Comment: If you want it to create cell's for `$_POST` so then let me update the code..!